# Test if a vector contains a given element

Tags: r, vector, r-faq

How to check if a vector contains a given value?

Comment: sometimes I ask myself why R just doesn't use the word contains to make it users easier

Comment: consider that "in" is contained in "conta(in)s"; I'd contend that "in" is a considerably concise contender in this context

Comment: Perhaps with the addition of flanking `%`-signs that is. The word `in` is a reserved word in R use in for-loop construction.

Comment: @greg121 dplyr already has a [contains](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/select_helpers.html) function, but it's used for a different purpose: to select a column in a data frame. For example `select(iris, contains("etal"))`.

Comment: Is there a concise way to do it for real valued numbers with a given precision?

Comment: @mlt - sure, but that's probably a new question.

Comment: @greg121 `in` also exist in popular languages such as JavaScript, Python and SQL, so not sure what so special about in R in particular- I would even bet R creators took it from one of them.

Answer (score 602, accepted):

Both the `match()` (returns the first appearance) and `%in%` (returns a Boolean) functions are designed for this.

```
v <- c('a','b','c','e')

'b' %in% v
## returns TRUE

match('b',v)
## returns the first location of 'b', in this case: 2
```

Comment: what about getting all appearances, not just the first one?

Comment: Maybe I come a little late. `which(v, 'b')`. Mind the order of the arguments.

Comment: Your `which(v, 'b')` gives me an error message:
>Error in which(v, 'b') : argument to 'which' is not logical

Comment: The syntax is which(v == b) or any other logical operator. In this case, the return from this would be 2. If v were c("b", "b", "c", "b", "d"), the return to which(v == b) would be 1, 2, 4.

Answer (score 207):

`is.element()` makes for more readable code, and is identical to `%in%`

```
v <- c('a','b','c','e')

is.element('b', v)
'b' %in% v
## both return TRUE

is.element('f', v)
'f' %in% v
## both return FALSE

subv <- c('a', 'f')
subv %in% v
## returns a vector TRUE FALSE
is.element(subv, v)
## returns a vector TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: I know the documentation says `is.element(x, y) is identical to x %in% y`. But, I dont know why, `is.elements` works when mixing integers and numerics and `%in%` doesn't

Comment: @pomber : Could you give an example of this?

Comment: @pomber is it fixed?

Comment: The superior readability `is.element()` vs `%in%` is subjective. A case can be made that an infix operator is more readable because it eliminates ambiguity in the order of arguments. `apple in fruit` makes sense, `fruit in apple` does not. `is.element(apple, fruit)` or `is.element(fruit, apple)` could both be right depending on implementation of the `is.element` function.

Answer (score 121):

I will group the options based on output. Assume the following vector for all the examples.

```
v <- c('z', 'a','b','a','e')
```

***For checking presence:***

**%in%**

```
> 'a' %in% v
[1] TRUE
```

**any()**

```
> any('a'==v)
[1] TRUE
```

**is.element()**

```
> is.element('a', v)
[1] TRUE
```

***For finding first occurance:***

**match()**

```
> match('a', v)
[1] 2
```

***For finding all occurances as vector of indices:***

**which()**

```
> which('a' == v)
[1] 2 4
```

***For finding all occurances as logical vector***:

**==**

```
> 'a' == v
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Edit:
Removing **grep()** and **grepl()** from the list for reason mentioned in comments

Comment: As already commented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169248/r-function-for-testing-if-a-vector-contains-a-given-element/34056066#comment66181358_34056066) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169248/r-function-for-testing-if-a-vector-contains-a-given-element/34056066#comment73025314_34056066), don't use `grep()` or regular expressions to find exact matches.

Answer (score 71):

The **any()** function makes for readable code

```
> w <- c(1,2,3)
> any(w==1)
[1] TRUE

> v <- c('a','b','c')
> any(v=='b')
[1] TRUE

> any(v=='f')
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: Be aware this behaves differently from `%in%`: `any(1==NA)` returns `NA`, where `1 %in% NA` returns `FALSE`.

Comment: @user3603486: `any(1==NA, na.rm=TRUE)` returns `FALSE`.

Answer (score 37):

You can use the `%in%` operator:

```
vec <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
1 %in% vec # true
10 %in% vec # false
```

Answer (score 20):

Also to find the position of the element "which" can be used as

```
pop <- c(3, 4, 5, 7, 13)

which(pop==13)
```

and to find the elements which are not contained in the target vector, one may do this:

```
pop <- c(1, 2, 4, 6, 10)

Tset <- c(2, 10, 7)   # Target set

pop[which(!(pop%in%Tset))]
```

Comment: `which` is actually preferable sometimes for it gives you *all* the matching positions (as an array), unlike `match`. Although this was perhaps not what the OP asked for, unlike http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169388/finding-multiple-elements-in-a-vector

Comment: Why bother with `which` if you just want to find the elements not in `Tset`? You can just index `pop` directly; `pop[!pop%in%Tset]`

Answer (score 13):

I really like grep() and grepl() for this purpose.

grep() returns a vector of integers, which indicate where matches are.

```
yo <- c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c")

grep("b", yo)
[1] 3 4
```

grepl() returns a logical vector, with "TRUE" at the location of matches.

```
yo <- c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c")

grepl("b", yo)
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

These functions are case-sensitive.

Comment: By default, `grep` takes a regular expression as its first element, so  to do an exact match for `"b"`, either use`^e$` or add `, fixed=TRUE`).

Comment: Do not use regex for exact matches. This is dangerous and can have unexpected results

Comment: Yeah, this is a terrible, no good, very bad idea - inefficient and guaranteed to break. E.g. `myvar <- 'blah'; grepl('b', myvar, fixed=TRUE)` will return `TRUE` even though 'b' is not in `myvar`.

Answer (score 1):

Another option to check if a element exists in a vector is by using the `%in{}%` syntax from the `inops` [package](https://github.com/moodymudskipper/inops) like this:

```r
library(inops)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'inops'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     <<-
v <- c('a','b','c','e')
v %in{}% c("b")
#> [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>