# Finding All Positions for Multiple Elements in a Vector

Tags: r, vector, r-faq

Suppose I have the following vector:

```
x <- c(8, 6, 9, 9, 7, 3, 2, 5, 5, 1, 6, 8, 5, 2, 9, 3, 5, 10, 8, 2)
```

How can I find which elements are either 8 or 9?

Comment: If you meant "detect all duplicated elements". R has a useful fn `duplicated`, and you can get all duplicates with duplicated(x) | duplicated(x, fromLast=T)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This is one way to do it.  First I get the indices at which x is either 8 or 9.  Then we can verify that at those indices, x is indeed 8 and 9.

```
> inds <- which(x %in% c(8,9))
> inds
[1]  1  3  4 12 15 19
> x[inds]
[1] 8 9 9 8 9 8
```

Comment: But suppose I'm looking for the specific indexes of two values without their orders sorted. How would I get a result of "26, 1" instead of "1, 26" if I'm looking for the indexes of Z and A in the alphabet?

_which( letters %in% c( 'z', 'a' ) )_

Comment: @dasf use any kind of sort, like bubblesort

Comment: This should be the upvoted answer...

Answer (score 11):

You could try the `|` operator for short conditions

```
which(x == 8 | x == 9)
```

Answer (score 2):

In ***this specific case*** you could also use `grep`:

```
# option 1
grep('[89]',x)
# option 2
grep('8|9',x)
```

which both give:

```
[1]  1  3  4 12 15 19
```

When you also want to detect number with more than one digit, the second option is preferred:

```
> grep('10|8',x)
[1]  1 12 18 19
```

However, I did put emphasis on ***this specific case*** at the start of my answer for a reason. [As @DavidArenburg mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169388/finding-all-positions-for-multiple-elements-in-a-vector#comment60649308_1185200), this could lead to unintended results. Using for example `grep('1|8',x)` will detect both `1` and `10`:

```
> grep('1|8',x)
[1]  1 10 12 18 19
```

In order to avoid that side-effect, you will have to wrap the numbers to be detected in word-bounderies:

```
> grep('\\b1\\b|8',x)
[1]  1 10 12 19
```

Now, the `10` isn't detected.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a generalized solution to find the locations of all target values (only works for vectors and 1-dimensional arrays).

```
locate <- function(x, targets) {
    results <- lapply(targets, function(target) which(x == target))
    names(results) <- targets
    results
}
```

This function returns a list because each target may have any number of matches, including zero. The list is sorted (and named) in the original order of the targets.

Here is an example in use:

```
sequence <- c(1:10, 1:10)

locate(sequence, c(2,9))
$`2`
[1]  2 12

$`9`
[1]  9 19
```

Comment: nice function it would be better if it returned a vector

Comment: locate <- function(x, targets) {
  results <- lapply(targets, function(target) which(x == target))
  unlist(results)
}

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you do not need to use the indices but just the elements you can do

```
> x <- sample(1:10,20,replace=TRUE)
> x
 [1]  6  4  7  2  9  3  3  5  4  7  2  1  4  9  1  6 10  4  3 10
> x[8<=x & x<=9]
[1] 9 9
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find the answer using loops, then the following script will do the job:

```
> req_nos<- c(8,9)
> pos<-list()
> for (i in 1:length(req_nos)){
  pos[[i]]<-which(x==req_nos[i])}
```

The output will look like this:

```
>pos
[[1]]
[1] 1 12 19
[[2]] 
[1] 3  4 15
```

Here, pos[[1]] contains positions of 8 and pos[[2]] contains positions of 9. If you are using the %in% method and change the input order of elements, i.e, c(9,8) instead of c(8,9), the output will be the same for both of them. This method alleviates such problem.

Answer (score -1):

`grepl` maybe a useful function.  Note that `grepl` appears in versions of R 2.9.0 and later.  What's handy about `grepl` is that it returns a logical vector of the same length as `x`.

```
grepl(8, x)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[13] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

grepl(9, x)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[13] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

To arrive at your answer, you could do the following

```
grepl(8,x) | grepl(9,x)
```

Comment: I like grepl as well, great for filtering dataframes on text strings, etc. Thanks for the OR example - I thought it would be that simple, but I kept trying `||` which is the wrong syntax.

Comment: This is a very dangerous solution. `grepl(9, c(9, 99, 654649))` will return `TRUE` for all of these. One should be very careful with exact matches and regex.