# dplyr filter : value is contained in a vector

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

Is there a straight way to filter using `dplyr::filter` given an specific vector?

I'm looking for something like the code below:

```
top.food <- c('pizza', 'bacon', 'burger')

filter(orders, dish == 'pizza' | dish == 'bacon' | dish == 'burger')
```

*I've chosen a character vector but it could be of any class.*

I've thought about using grepl as a logical predicate `grepl(dish, top.food)` but it doesn't work since dish doesn't match a valid pattern (it takes just the 1st element).

Any ideas? thnx!

Comment: Look like a [r-faq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169388/finding-multiple-elements-in-a-vector) to me

Answer (score 48):

I think you are looking for the value matching function `%in%`.

```
filter(orders, dish %in% top.food)
```

Or you can switch to `slice()` and use `match()`.

```
slice(orders, match(dish, top.food, 0L))
```

I believe that `slice()` is a bit faster than `filter()`, so that might be beneficial to you.  See `help(match)` for all the details on value matching.