# Finding ALL indices of positions in vector matching columns of DF in R

Tags: r, match

I have a dataframe  A whose columns I want to match with the row.names of another dataframe B.

```
# A
v1    v2    
X1    X3
X1    X5
X1    X15
X2    X3
X2    X4
...


# row.names of B (some values are duplicated)
row_names_B=c('X17', 'X1', 'X2', 'X15', 'X3', 'X3', 'X1', 'X5', 'X4', ...)
```

I want to match the columns of `A` with the positions of `row_names_B`, such that I can return a list of ALL positions in B for each row in A.

```
#my results:
v1_index    v2_index
2           5        #matches X1 in pos 2, X3 in pos 5
2           6        #matches X1 in pos 2, X3 in pos 6
7           5        #matches X1 in pos 7, X3 in pos 5
7           6        #matches X1 in pos 7, X3 in pos 6
2           5        #matches X1 in pos 2, X3 in pos 8
7           5        #matches X1 in pos 7, X3 in pos 8
...
```

Note that I want to find all possible solutions.

I understand that this should be with some variant of `match` or `which` as given [in this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1169399/1379826), but I'm not sure how to do the explosion for each of the matches. The way I see it is by running it through `for` loops, row by row, but perhaps there is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a list of position based on their name and randomly assign one value in the dataframe `A` from the list of positions.

```
C <- A
ref <- split(seq_along(row_names_B), row_names_B)
C[] <- lapply(A, function(y) sapply(ref[y], 
                    function(x) if(length(x) == 1) x else sample(x, 1)))
C

#  v1 v2
#1  2  5
#2  2  8
#3  7  4
#4  3  5
#5  3  9
```

**data**

```
A <- structure(list(v1 = c("X1", "X1", "X1", "X2", "X2"), v2 = c("X3", 
"X5", "X15", "X3", "X4")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
row_names_B <- c("X17", "X1", "X2", "X15", "X3", "X3", "X1", "X5", "X4")
```

Comment: Why is `v1_index` for 1st 2 values 2 and next 2 7 ?

Comment: So why 1st 2 values go for position 2 and next 2 to 7? Why not 2, 7, 2, 7 or any different combination?

Comment: Yes, that is because I am using `sample` here. You can add `set.seed` before running the code to get consistent results.

Comment: `X1` values reflect to `X1` position so first 3 values in `v1` would be either 2 and 7. Next 2 values are `X2` and `X2` has only 1 position in the vector that I have used so the value is always 3. Same goes for `v2` column.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your requirement. How are pairs related here? I thought every number is an individual number.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I ran this multiple times and I get only 2 and 7 in every output. I don't get 3 at all for `X1` and this is what exactly code is supposed to do as well.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, in data part it should be `A` and then we do `C <- A`. I have updated the answer.

Comment: alright, I can now reproduce your results (though the row order varies)! :) however, I am still only getting 5 rows, but I need all the possible solutions. For instance, for the first row of `A` I should get the following rows in `C`: `2 5` and `2 6` (for `X1` in position `2` and `X3` in positions `5` and `6`), and `7 5` and `7 6` (for `X1` in position `7` and `X3` in positions `5` and `6`). I will delete my previous comments too