# What is the alternate to 'in' command we have in Python, for R?

Tags: r, if-statement, vector

Say I have a numerical vector in R. And I want to see if a particular integer is present in the vector or not. We can do that easily in python using 'in' command and an if statement may be.

Do we have something similar in R as well? So that I don't have to use a for loop to check if the integer I want is present in a vector? I tried the following, but it does not seem to work. 'normal' is a dataframe and the second column has integers.

```
if (12069692 in normal[,2]) {print("yes")}
```

Says,

```
Error: unexpected 'in' in "if (12069692 in"
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but -1 for a lack of research effort. If I google *R find value in vector*, first hit is, I believe, a [duplicate of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1169248/1478381)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In R, it's called `%in%`:

```
> 1 %in% c(1, 2, 3)
[1] TRUE
> 4 %in% c(1, 2, 3)
[1] FALSE
```

It is vectorized on the left-hand side, so you can check multiple values at once:

```
> c(1, 4, 2, 1) %in% c(1, 2, 3)
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

(hat tip @Spacedman)

Comment: Ah! That was simple. This %in% datatype was always hard for me to understand. Thanks!

Comment: And its vectorised on the LHS: `c(1,2,4,5) %in% c(1, 2, 3)` is `TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE`.

Comment: I voted to close the question as duplicate, but +1 for the useful answer.