# Keeping only certain rows of a data frame based on a set of values

Tags: r, subset

I have a data frame with an ID column and a few columns for values. I would like to only keep certain rows of the data frame based on whether or not the value of ID at that row matches another set of values (for instance, called "keep").

For simplicity, here is an example:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = sample(rep(letters, each=3)), value = rnorm(n=26*3))
keep <- c("a", "d", "r", "x")
```

How can I create a new data frame consisting of rows that only have IDs that match those of keep? I can do this for just one letter by using the `which()` function, but with multiple letters I get warning messages and incorrect returns. I know I could run a for loop through the data frame and extrapolate that way, but I'm wondering if there is a more elegant and efficient way of going about this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try df[df$ID %in% keep, ] or subset(df, ID %in% keep) -- see http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sets.html

Answer (score 30):

Try `df[df$ID %in% keep, ]` or `subset(df, ID %in% keep)` -- see the help page for [sets](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sets.html).

Edit: Also, if this were for a single letter, you could write e.g. `df[df$ID == "a", ]` instead of using `which()`.

Edit: the `is.element` function also works (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/19136456/610668):

```
> df <- data.frame(id=c("A", "B", "C"), x=c(5, 22, 88)) 
> df[df$id %in% c("B", "C"), ]
  id  x
2  B 22
3  C 88
> df[is.element(df$id, c("B", "C")), ]
  id  x
2  B 22
3  C 88
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much! I do know about the other method of extrapolating just one letter, but I have been using the `which()` method throughout my history with R and it looks syntactically prettier to me (if that makes any sense....) so I stick with it :)