# R compare multiple values with vector and return vector

Tags: r

I have a vector "A", and for each element of A I want to check whether it is equal to any element from a second vector "Targets". I want a vector of logical values with the length of A as return.

The same problem is mentioned [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/compare-multiple-values-with-vector-and-return-vector-td1749724.html). Here is a related discussion of [how to test if a vector contains a specific value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169248/r-function-for-testing-if-a-vector-contains-a-given-element), but I did not know how to apply this to my question because I want a vector as output and not a single boolean.

Here is example code:

```
#example data
A <- c(rep("A",4),rep(c("B","C"),8))
Targets <- c("A","C","D")
```

I would like a vector which tells me for each element of A if it is equal to at least one of the elements in Targets. For the example, this should produce a vector that is identical with:

```
result <- c(rep("TRUE",4), rep(c("FALSE","TRUE"), 8))
```

In case this is relevant, eventually vector A will be much longer (ca 20000 elements), and the vector Targets will contain approximately 30 elements.

Comment: I am confused because the answer that helped me has now disappeared.
it was: 
sapply(A, `%in%`, Targets) or
sapply(A, function(x) x %in% Targets)

Comment: I deleted my answer because it was complicating things, as nicola pointed out in a comment. All you need to do is `A %in% Targets`, i.e. no extra looping with `sapply` is required.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just try:

```
 A %in% Targets
```

The `%in%` function tells you if each element of the first argument equals one of the elements of the second argument, that's exactly what you are looking for.