# Replace all occurrences not matching any regex element of a vector of values in an R data frame

Tags: r

I'm trying to replace all occurrences not matching any element of a pre-specified list or vector of values (including regex) in an R data frame. I want to perform the operation across all columns such that each occurrence not matching any element of the list is replaced with another value (e.g., NA).

For example, suppose my vector is `vec <- c('D47Z', 'D98K', 'D75.')` where the last element `D75.` is specifying `D75X` where `X` is any character (`D75.` being regex syntax for D75 followed by any character denoted `.`).

I'm able to use regex like this for most other purposes in R, and I've figured out how to do this when regex is not specified but rather a list is fully enumerated for all elements (i.e., enumerating all regex elements manually) but I've been stuck on how to do this with regex. There's a million ways to do this if we're just talking about one column, but I want to apply this to multiple columns at once, i.e. every column that is of character type.

When regex is not specified, I can do it in two lines:

```
`%ni%` <- Negate(`%in%`)
df <- lapply(df, function(x){x[x %ni% c('D47Z', 'D98K', 'D75A', 'D57D')] <- NA; x})
```

Essentially what I'm asking is what is asked in the parenthesized post ([Recode string values to NA if *not* in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55252891/recode-string-values-to-na-if-not-in-list)), but I'd like to recode all values across all columns allowing for the elements of the vector/list to be specified by regex rather than being fully enumerated.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Staying close to the apprached syntax, we can do:

```r
pattern = c('D47Z', 'D98K', 'D75[A-Z]')
example = data.frame(A = c('D47Z', 'D98K', 'D'), B = c("LL3", "ABC", "D75Y"))
example[] = 
  lapply(example, \(x) replace(x, !grepl(paste0(pattern, collapse = "|"), x), NA))
```

gives

```r
> example
     A    B
1 D47Z <NA>
2 D98K <NA>
3 <NA> D75Y
```

You may want a different regex than `[A-Z]`.

Answer (score 1):

does one of the two options below (using `vec` or `vec2`) already the job for you?

```
vec <- c("D47Z|D98K|D75[A-Z]")

vec2 <- c("^D47Z$|^D98K$|^D75[A-Z]$")
  
dat <- tibble(
  id = 1:9,
  v1 = c("D47Z", "D98K", "D756", "A47Z", "B98K", "D75C", "D17Z", "D92K", "D753"),
  v2 = c("D97Z", "D88K", "D75A", "D47Z", "D98K", "D75R", "D47Z", "D98K", "D75E"),
  v3 = paste(v1, "D", sep = ""),
  v4 = paste("D", v1, sep = "")
  )

dat %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("v"), function(x) str_extract(x, vec)))

dat %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("v"), function(x) str_extract(x, vec2)))
```