# Difference between df["speed"] and df$speed

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose a data frame `df` has a column `speed`, then what is difference in the way accessing the column like so:

```
df["speed"]
```

or like so:

```
df$speed
```

The following calculates the mean value correctly:

```
lapply(df["speed"], mean)
```

But this prints all values under the column speed:

```
lapply(df$speed, mean)
```

Comment: `df["speed"] ` returns you a dataframe whereas `df$speed` returns a numeric vector. Check `class(df["speed"] )` and `class(df$speed)` and most probably you just need `mean(df$speed)`, no need of `lapply`.

Comment: not sure why is this question downvoted

Comment: @RichScriven So is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169248/r-function-for-testing-if-a-vector-contains-a-given-element).

Comment: Pooja, it might be informative to read [`help('[.data.frame')`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.data.frame.html). Note that `df["speed"]` is similar to `df[,"speed",drop=FALSE]`, and `df$speed` is similar to `df[,"speed"]` and `df[["speed"]]`. Confusing, perhaps, but documented.

Comment: I think it's a fair question. It's clear and answerable, and it's one of those quirks of the R language. Unless somebody argues that it's been asked before already I vote to leave open.

Answer (score 4):

There are two elements to the question in the OP. The first element was addressed in the comments: `df["speed"]` is an object of type `data.frame()` whereas `df$speed` is a numeric vector. We can see this via the `str()` function.

We'll illustrate this with Ezekiel's 1930 analysis of speed and stopping distance, the `cars` data set from the `datasets` package.

```
> library(datasets)
> data(cars)
> 
> str(cars["speed"])
'data.frame':   50 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ speed: num  4 4 7 7 8 9 10 10 10 11 ...
> str(cars$speed)
 num [1:50] 4 4 7 7 8 9 10 10 10 11 ...
>
```

The second element that was not addressed in the comments is that `lapply()` behaves differently when passed a vector versus a `list()`.

With a vector, `lapply()` processes each element in the vector independently, producing unexpected results for a function such as `mean()`.

```
> unlist(lapply(cars$speed,mean))
 [1]  4  4  7  7  8  9 10 10 10 11 11 12 12 12 12 13 13 13 13 14 14 14 14 15 15
[26] 15 16 16 17 17 17 18 18 18 18 19 19 19 20 20 20 20 20 22 23 24 24 24 24 25
```

### What happened?

Since each element of `cars$speed` is processed by `mean()` independently, `lapply()` returns a list of 50 means of 1 number each: the original elements in the `cars$speed` vector.

### Processing a list with `lapply()`

With a list, each element of the list is processed independently. We can calculate how many items will be processed by `lapply()` with the `length()` function.

```
> length(cars["speed"])
[1] 1
>
```

Since a data frame is also a `list()` that contains one element of type `data.frame()`, the `length()` function returns the value 1. Therefore, when processed by `lapply()`, a single mean is calculated, not one per row of the `speed` column.

```
> lapply(cars["speed"],mean)
$speed
[1] 15.4

>
```

If we pass the entire `cars` data frame as the input object for `lapply()`, we obtain one mean per column in the data frame, since both variables in the data frame are numeric.

```
> lapply(cars,mean)
$speed
[1] 15.4

$dist
[1] 42.98

>
```

### A theoretical perspective

The differing behaviors of `lapply()` are explained by the fact that R is an object oriented language. In fact, [John Chambers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Chambers_(statistician)), creator of the S language on which R is based, once said:

> In R, two slogans are helpful.
>
> -- Everything that exists is an object, and
>     -- Everything that happens is a function call.

John Chambers, quoted in *Advanced R,* p. 79.

The fact that `lapply()` works differently on a data frame than a vector is an illustration of the object oriented feature of [polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)) where the same behavior is implemented in different ways for different types of objects.

Comment: THX for supporting new R and SO users to learn R by posting a tutorial-alike answer. I think we should care about new R users by guiding them to right documentation ("learning to learn" :-)

Comment: @RYoda -- I agree we should guide people to the right documentation, but some of the R documentation is very cryptic, e.g. [help for the Extract Operator](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html). Another challenge for new R users is that they often don't know what questions to ask or how to ask them, as evidenced by all the comments referencing [How to Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help) on questions posted by people with <100 reputation. Tutorial style answers help people see solutions through working software.

Answer (score 2):

*While this looks like an beginner's question I think it's worth answering it since many beginners could have a similar question and a guide to the corresponding documentation is helpful IMHO.*

**No up-votes please - I am just collecting the comment fragments from the question that contribute to the answer - feel free to edit this answer...***

1. A `data.frame` is a list of vectors with the same length (number of elements). Please read the help in the R console (by typing `?data.frame`)
2. The `$` operator is implemented by returning one column as vector (`?"$.data.frame"`)
3. `lapply` applies a function to each element of a list (see `?lapply`). If the first param `X` is a scalar vector (integer, double...) with multiple elements, **each element of the vector** is converted ("coerced") into one separate list element (same as `as.list(1:26)`)

**Examples:**

```
x <- data.frame(a = LETTERS, b = 1:26, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
b.vector <- x$b
b.data.frame <- x["b"]
class(b.vector)       # integer
class(b.data.frame)   # data.frame

lapply(b.vector, mean)
# returns a result list with 26 list elements, the same as `lapply(1:26, mean)`
# [[1]]
# [1] 1
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 2
# ... up to list element 26

lapply(b.data.frame, mean)
# returns a list where each element of the input vector in param X
# becomes a separate list element (same as `as.list(1:26)`)
# $b
# [1] 13.5
```

So IMHO your original question can be reduced to: Why is `lapply` behaving differently if the first parameter is a scalar vector instead of a list?