# Create new conditional column if string contains elements from list

Tags: r, list, dplyr

I'm trying to add a new column `keywords` that will get the value `TRUE` if the word occurs in a list of keywords. The value will be `FALSE` if the word doesn't occur in the `keywordslist`. My keywords consists of more than 100 words, so manually adding the words is not an option.

keywordlist(sample):

```
thank
impressed
this
```

I have a dataframe with the values `id` and `word`, I have unnested the words and grouped by id:

```
id      word
1234    thank
1234    you
1234    very
1234    much
1567    i
1567    am
1567    not
1567    impressed
9654    what
9654    is
9654    this
```

I would like the result to look like this:

```
id      word       keywords
1234    thank      TRUE
1234    you        FALSE
1234    very       FALSE
1234    much       FALSE
1567    i          FALSE
1567    am         FALSE
1567    not        FALSE
1567    impressed  TRUE
9654    what       FALSE
9654    is         FALSE
9654    this       TRUE
```

The codes that I have tried is as followed:
1. :

```
df <- df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(keywords = ifelse(
  word == rowwise(keywordslist), TRUE, FALSE)
```

code #1 raises the next error:

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) :    Evaluation error:
>   is.data.frame(data) is not TRUE.

2. I have tried a little different variant with grepl:

   `df <- df %>%
     group_by(id) %>%
     mutate(keywords = ifelse(
     word == rowwise(grepl(keywordslist, word)), TRUE,FALSE)`

This raised the following error:

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) :    Evaluation error:
>   is.data.frame(data) is not TRUE. In addition: Warning message: In
>   grepl(keywordslist, keywords) :   argument 'pattern' has length > 1
>   and only the first element will be used

I'm not sure if this is the correct way to approach this situation anymore. Any help is welcome.

Comment: Try `keywords <- df$word %in% keywordlist`.

Comment: This might be helpful to understand. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169248/test-if-a-vector-contains-a-given-element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
library(dplyr)

 df1 %>% 
  mutate(keywords = word %in% keywordlist)

#  id      word keywords
#1  1234     thank     TRUE
#2  1234       you    FALSE
#3  1234      very    FALSE
#4  1234      much    FALSE
#5  1567         i    FALSE
#6  1567        am    FALSE
#7  1567       not    FALSE
#8  1567 impressed     TRUE
#9  9654      what    FALSE
#10 9654        is    FALSE
#11 9654      this     TRUE
```

or with with `base` R

```
df1$keywords <- sapply(df1, function(x) x %in% keywordlist)[,2]


#   id      word keywords
#1  1234     thank     TRUE
#2  1234       you    FALSE
#3  1234      very    FALSE
#4  1234      much    FALSE
#5  1567         i    FALSE
#6  1567        am    FALSE
#7  1567       not    FALSE
#8  1567 impressed     TRUE
#9  9654      what    FALSE
#10 9654        is    FALSE
#11 9654      this     TRUE
```

Comment: Is there a way to use this ```base``` R function on a column with a specific name? (in case that column is in a different place in each dataset)

Answer (score 3):

```
df$keywords <- df$word %in% keywordslist
```

should do it

Comment: I didn't understand the role of grouping by `id` though - so that is not included in my answer.

Comment: and I presumed that `keywordslist` is a character vector (and so i s `df$word`) -

Comment: Thanks! it was much easier than I thought.

Answer (score 0):

`dplyr` approach could be

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(keywords = grepl(paste(keywordlist, collapse = "|"), word))
```

which gives

```
     id      word keywords
1  1234     thank     TRUE
2  1234       you    FALSE
3  1234      very    FALSE
4  1234      much    FALSE
5  1567         i    FALSE
6  1567        am    FALSE
7  1567       not    FALSE
8  1567 impressed     TRUE
9  9654      what    FALSE
10 9654        is    FALSE
11 9654      this     TRUE
```

**Sample data:**

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1234L, 1234L, 1234L, 1234L, 1567L, 1567L, 
1567L, 1567L, 9654L, 9654L, 9654L), word = c("thank", "you", 
"very", "much", "i", "am", "not", "impressed", "what", "is", 
"this")), .Names = c("id", "word"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))

keywordlist <- c("thank", "impressed", "this")
```