# R - adding a value to a new row if column name matches a string

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a very large data.table with the structure below:

```
variant ID1 ID2 ID3 ID4 .... ID80000
123     0    1   2   1         0
321     1    2   1   1         1
543     1    1   2   1         1
6542    1    0   0   1         0  
243     1    0   2   1         1
654     0    1   1   2         1 
342     1    2   1   2         1
```

I would like to add a row with a 0 or 1 dependant on whether the ID in a string is present in the above table.

Say I have the a list:
a <- c("ID42", "ID4")

The desired output would be:

```
variant ID1 ID2 ID3 ID4 .... ID80000
123     0    1   2   1         0
321     1    2   1   1         1
543     1    1   2   1         1
6542    1    0   0   1         0  
243     1    0   2   1         1
654     0    1   1   2         1 
342     1    2   1   2         1
present 0    1   0   1         0
```

A bit like this question but in rows: [Create new conditional column if string contains elements from list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50870731/create-new-conditional-column-if-string-contains-elements-from-list)

I have tried:

```
df$present <- colnames(df) %in% id_list
```

But I get an error as it says there are too many rows.

Many thanks for your help

Would an ifelse be helpful here?

Comment: `df$present <- ` creates a new *column*. It looks like you want a new *row*. `rbind` and `df['present', ] <- ` come to mind for adding a row.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that monumental failure!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a similar structure as your df, and append a row to the dataframe.

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=10, nrow=0)) 
colnames(df) <- c("variant", rep(paste0("ID",2:ncol(df))))
a <- c("ID42", "ID4")
df[nrow(df) + 1,] <- c("present", ifelse(colnames(df) %in% a, 1, 0)[-1])
df

variant ID2 ID3 ID4 ID5 ID6 ID7 ID8 ID9 ID10
present   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0    0
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @sashahafner above:

```
I got df['present',] <-colnames(df) %in% id_list
```

to work, not sure it's the best solution but hey ho!

Comment: Hi @tacrolimus. Don't know if this is important but your solution leads to having "present" as `rowname`. But in the desired result indicated in your question "present" is in the `variant` column...

Comment: thanks for taking the time to have a look. Yes that's what I was hoping for!

Comment: O.K. if you got the result you were hoping for, then everything is fine. Cheers.