# Check if elements of vector are equal to the elements of another vector +/- 1 in R

Tags: r

I would like to check if the elements of a vector are equal to the elements of another vector +/- 1, and count the number of times this is true. I could do it manually this way:

```
> a <- c(1:10)
> b <- c(1,2,3,4,6,5,10,11,12,13)
> sum(a == b-1) + sum(a == b) + sum(a == b+1)
[1] 6
```

Is there a neater way to achieve this? In the code I'm trying to write I'm using fairly long index vectors for both `a` and `b`, so the above would look quite messy.

Comment: Maybe just use "or", as in `sum(a == b-1 | a == b | a == b+1)`

Comment: `sum(abs(a - b) <= 1)` ?

Comment: I think this post is what you need:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169248/test-if-a-vector-contains-a-given-element