# Find top-level element that contains a sub-element in a nested list

Tags: r

I would like to get a list of top level elements that contain a particular sub-element. Suppose I have a nested list:

```
v <- list(A=list('a', 'b', 'c'), B=list('c','d','e'), C=list('d'))
```

I am trying to get the list of all top-level elements that have a particular sub element:

- if I am looking for 'c' I would expect to get ('A', 'B').
- if I am looking for 'd' I would expect to get ('B', 'C')

NOTE: prefer a base-R solution but would be interesting to see others

Comment: Must it be a list-of-lists, rather than [`base` package which has set operations like `is.element`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sets.html) on vectors, or `dplyr::setops`, or `data.table::setops` ?

Comment: Related question: [Test if a vector contains a given element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169248/test-if-a-vector-contains-a-given-element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Filter` :

```
names(Filter(function(x) "c" %in% x,v))
# [1] "A" "B"
names(Filter(function(x) "d" %in% x,v))
# [1] "B" "C"
```

Or with library *purrr* :

```
names(purrr::keep(v, ~"c" %in% .))
# [1] "A" "B"
names(purrr::modify_if(v, ~!"c" %in% ., ~NULL))
# [1] "A" "B"
```

Comment: awesome, exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

`sapply` alternative to `Filter`

```
names(v)[sapply(v, function(x) 'c' %in% x)]
```