# Check for a match between a list of values and a column entry in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataset with a column `Disease` that contains string values. I also have a list of names with rare diseases `rare_disease`.

I want to check, for each cell of the column `Disease`, whether it contains an element from the list `rare_disease` and if so, to create a new column in my dataframe and give the value 1 to that entry.

I tried using the `ifelse` function, like so:

```
FinalData$RareDisease <- ifelse(rare_disease %in% FinalData$Disease,1,0)
```

But I guess that checks whether the the corresponding rows in both variables are the same, so it throws an error. Instead, I want every cell of `Disease` to be checked against every single element of `rare_disease`, if that makes sense.

I have also tried `match` and `is.element()` as suggested here [Test if a vector contains a given element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169248/test-if-a-vector-contains-a-given-element) but they don't work either.

Comment: Shouldn't it be ifelse(FinalData$Disease %in% rare_disease,1,0)

Comment: I think you need to flip it: `FinalData$RareDisease <- ifelse(FinalData$Disease %in% rare_disease, 1, 0)`

Comment: From your previous post, I think you want regex match, not exact match: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55907952/680068 , please provide example input, and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a reproducible example/solution -- noting you can just use `as.numeric` instead of `ifelse`:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  idx = 1:10,
  Disease = letters[1:10]
)
rare_disease <- letters[c(1, 5, 9)]

df
#>    idx Disease
#> 1    1       a
#> 2    2       b
#> 3    3       c
#> 4    4       d
#> 5    5       e
#> 6    6       f
#> 7    7       g
#> 8    8       h
#> 9    9       i
#> 10  10       j
rare_disease
#> [1] "a" "e" "i"

df$RareDisease <- as.numeric(df$Disease %in% rare_disease)
df
#>    idx Disease RareDisease
#> 1    1       a           1
#> 2    2       b           0
#> 3    3       c           0
#> 4    4       d           0
#> 5    5       e           1
#> 6    6       f           0
#> 7    7       g           0
#> 8    8       h           0
#> 9    9       i           1
#> 10  10       j           0
```

<sup>Created on 2019-04-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, that still gives all 0s in my data so I guess there's probably a problem in the formatting, I'll have a look. That should still work if `rare_disease` is a dataframe, right?

Comment: @FloranThovan The above should work if `rare_disease` is a vector. If `rare_disease` is a `data.frame`, you would need to do: `(df$Disease %in% df_rare_disease$rare_disease)`. This is why creating reproducible example is preferred.

Comment: Ah, got it. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You are almost right, but you should flip it:

```
FinalData$RareDisease <- ifelse(rare_disease %in% FinalData$Disease,1,0)
```