# How to use or (" | ") in ifelse in r programming for categorial value

Tags: r

For example, I want to make a subcategory from column data1 to data2. It will categorize if A or B, and it will put a value of 1 for it, else 0.

```
Project_R2 $data2 = ifelse (Project_R2 $data1 =="A" | "B", 1,0).
```

This code is not working for me.

Comment: You would better use `%in%`, i.e. `ifelse(Project_R2$data1 %in% c("A", "B"), 1,0)` or maybe `as.integer(Project_R2$data1 %in% c("A", "B"))`

Comment: Relevant: [Test if a vector contains a given element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169248/test-if-a-vector-contains-a-given-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more options, so you can try this:

```
Project_R2$data2 = ifelse(Project_R2$data1 =="A" | Project_R2$data1 == "B", 1,0)
```

And as @markus mentioned in the comments, you can also use this:

```
Project_R2$data2 = ifelse(Project_R2$data1 %in% c("A", "B"), 1,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

With `%in%` you can test if elements are part of a set which makes it equivalent to `|` (as recommended by @Markus). It gives the same result

```r
Project_R2 <- data.frame(data1 = c("A", "C", "B", "D", "B", "A", "C", "D"))

Project_R2$data2 = ifelse(Project_R2$data1 %in% c("A", "B"), 1, 0)
Project_R2$data2
#> [1] 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0
```

Or even shorter but a bit less obvious to understand (`as.integer` coerces `TRUE` to `1` and `FALSE` to `0``)

```r
Project_R2$data2 = as.integer(Project_R2$data1 %in% c("A", "B"))
Project_R2$data2
#> [1] 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>