# Filter rows in data frame by multiple ranges in R

Tags: r, dplyr, filter, data-manipulation

I am trying to use `dplyr::filter` to select rows which fall within either of 2 value ranges (1:3 or 7:10) in the `Day` column.

Ultimately I would like to manipulate `df` in the MRE below so that it will contain the rows with Day values 1,2,3,7,8,9,10 from the entire data frame, including all IDs.

Trying to use the `|` operator below produces `df2` containing rows with value 1,2,3 for ID "A" only and 7,8,9,10 for ID "B" only.

```
library("dplyr")

ID <- rep(c("A","B","C"), each = 10)
Day <- rep(c(1:10), times = 3)
Fig <- sample(20:50, 30)

df <- data.frame(ID, Day, Fig)

df2 <- dplyr::filter(df, Day == 1:3 | Day == 7:10)
```

Comment: Since you're comparing with more than one items, use `%in%` instead of `==`. i.e. `dplyr::filter(df, Day %in% 1:3 | Day %in% 7:10)`

Comment: Learn more in [Test if a vector contains a given element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169248/test-if-a-vector-contains-a-given-element)

Answer (score 0):

Using `%in%` instead of `==` as recommended in the comments by benson23

```
library("dplyr")

ID <- rep(c("A","B","C"), each = 10)
Day <- rep(c(1:10), times = 3)
Fig <- sample(20:50, 30)

df <- data.frame(ID, Day, Fig)

df2 <- dplyr::filter(df, Day %in% 1:3 | Day %in% 7:10)
```

Comment: The condition can be more compact with `filter(df, Day %in% c(1:3, 7:10))`